# Classes and Substitutions in Scala

Tags: scala

Can someone explain to me how the method `union` exactly works in this code? I can see that it's calling itself in the function but other than that I don't get what it does. Printing `t2 union t3` yields `{{{.-1.}2.}3{{.4.}5{.7.}}}`.

```
object Mp6 {  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val t1 = Empty
    val t2 = t1 incl 3 incl 5 incl 4 incl 7
    val t3 = t2 incl 2 incl 4 incl -1

    println(t1)
    println(t2)
    println(t1 contains 5)
    println(t2 contains 5)
    println(t2 contains 5)

    println(t2 union t3)
  }
}

abstract class IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet
}

object Empty extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, Empty, Empty)  
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet = other
  override def toString = "."
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left contains x
    else if (x > elem) right contains x
    else true

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet =
    if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
    else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
    else this

  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet = {
    val set = left.union(right.union(other))
    set.incl(elem)
  }

  override def toString = "{" + left + elem + right + "}"
}
```

Comment: Looks very like it came from Coursera, and the honor code says not to share code from that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got this code from our instructor I had no idea where he got this from.

Comment: @Paul: this looks like a pretty standard OO encoding of sets, e.g. very similar to the one used by William R. Cook in "On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited".

Comment: OK.Unless Coursera also used it from somewhere else, it's looking a bit suspicious! Anyway, where exactly does your understanding of union stop? For teaching purposes, it's best not to explain everything from the start, I think

Comment: @JörgWMittag, yes, it does. The design is not the issue, it's that the  class, val, method names and layout are pretty much identical to Coursera. That's one heck of a coincidence.

Comment: @Paul: The union function is defined by (left union (right union other)) incl elem.  I understand that left and right pertains to the left and right subtrees, but I don't get which is the "other" and which is the "elem" since this deals with two non empty sets, and the use of "union" within the function confuses me since I don't see any other method of union. I'd like to see a substituent model if possible.

Comment: @RenzFitzgeraldIban: Do you mean "substitution model of evaluation"? It's hard to picture what's going on because there are many intermediate results. Have you tried smaller sets?

Comment: @StavrosMekesis: Yes, sorry for the typo, it would be easier for me to understand it that way.  I have not tried it with smaller sets, but I would still find it hard to understand, does other and elem represent sets or a single number?

Comment: @RenzFitzgeraldIban: `elem` has a type of `Int` and `other` has a type of `IntSet`. What have you tried? What is your background in Scala, by the way?

Comment: @StavrosMekesis: So if we have t1 = empty, t2 = t1 incl 1 incl 2, t3 = t1 incl 4 inlc 5 , when we perform t2 union t3, does scala test the t3 values on t2 or vice versa? I'm a complete newbie in Scala, our instructor had just finished discussing Class Hierarchies but I did not seem to understand him very well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're basically asking for an explanation of how the *substitution model of evaluation* works. As stated in the comments above, your code snippet closely resembles an implementation of `IntSets` written by Martin Odersky (the creator of Scala), so I'll use the notation from his course notes. I assume you've already taken a quick read through the substitution model rules. If not, [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) and [Scala by Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) are good places to start.

I'll give you a hint: Suppose, for the sake of convenience, that `val t1 = new NonEmpty(1, Empty, Empty)` and `val t2 = new NonEmpty(2, Empty, new NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty))`. This means that `t1: NonEmpty = {.1.}` and `t2: NonEmpty = {.2{.3.}}`. Now let's evaluate the expression `t1 union t2`.

```
t1 union t2 = new NonEmpty(1, Empty, Empty) union new NonEmpty(2, Empty, new NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty))
            → [1/elem, Empty/left, Empty/right] [new NonEmpty(2, Empty, new NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty))/other] [new NonEmpty(1, Empty, Empty)/this] (left union (right union other)) incl elem 
            = (Empty union (Empty union new NonEmpty(2, Empty, new NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty)))) incl 1
            ...
```

Can you complete the evaluation now?

Comment: Won't this end up to be non-terminating creating many instances of Empty sets? or am I supposed to omit all instances of Empty sets resulting in this:

     
    =new NonEmpty(2, Empty, new NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty)) incl 1
    =if(1 < 2) newNonEmpty(2, newNonEmpty(1, Empty, Empty), new      NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty))
    ={{.1.}2{.3.}}

Comment: Sorry for my text format, I've just started here in stack overflow.  How did you make it appear like code blocks in the comments?

Comment: Recall that `Empty union other` gives always `other`, so `(Empty union (Empty union new NonEmpty(2, Empty, new NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty)))) incl 1` evaluates to `new NonEmpty(2, Empty, new NonEmpty(3, Empty, Empty)) incl 1`. Yes, your final result is correct.

Comment: Regarding code formatting, have a look at this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

It's an implementation of a sorted integer set that works by backing with a binary sorted tree that does not add duplicates.  Therefore union just performs a set theoretic union where the order of the integers is preserved.